# How do I have the cursor placed in a dropdown field on page load using jsf?

Tags: jsf

when I load a page , the cursor must point to drop-down field , using jsf.I am new to JSF.

Comment: This does not sound like a good idea. I don't think any user will ever expect a web-application to move their mouse-cursor for them. You should rethink that approach.

Comment: @Björn I think he just wants to focus the first input component, which is not unusual or unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

When the page is finished loading in webbrowser, JSF has already done its job of generating a bunch of HTML on the webserver and sending it to the webbrowser. It can't do any much more for you after that point. You need to use JavaScript for this job. It is able to execute code when the page is finished loading and it has access to all elements in the HTML DOM tree.

So, if you specify a fixed ID for the dropdown element in JSF,

```
<h:form id="myform">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="mydropdown">
    ...
</h:form>
```

then you must be able to grab it by JavaScript:

```
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('myform:mydropdown');
```

In JavaScript, you can use [`element.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.focus) to set the focus on the element:

```
mydropdown.focus();
```

To get it to execute then the page is finished loading, you need to hook a function to [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('myform:mydropdown');
    mydropdown.focus();
}
```

That's it. Put it in a `<script>` somewhere near the bottom of the `<head>` or a `.js` file which you include by `<script src>`.

Comment: I tried the way u have said , its working fine. To improve that I tried this way :                                           window.onload = elementSetFocus2('myform:mydropdown');     
     
     function elementSetFocus2(id) {
   alert(id);
   var mydropdown = document.getElementById(id);
   alert(mydrowdown);
   mydrowdown.focus();
   alert('done');
  }

Comment: in alert(id) its picking the id above mentioned , but in alert(mydrowdown) its showing NULL , Dont know whats wrong , please help ....

Comment: Hi balus C , thanks for replying .I tried the way u have said , its working fine. To improve that I tried this way : window.onload = elementSetFocus2('myform:mydropdown'); function elementSetFocus2(id) { alert(id); var mydropdown = document.getElementById(id); alert(mydrowdown); mydrowdown.focus(); alert('done'); } ,                                                  In alert(id) its picking the id above mentioned , but in alert(mydrowdown) its showing NULL , Dont know whats wrong , please help

Comment: "mydropdown" != "mydrowdown".

Answer (score 0):

JSF is a server side technology and this type of behavior requires Javascript.  Try to write a Javascript to do this in a regular HTML page first.  Once you have figured out how to do this you can try to use this script in your JSF page.

Comment: JSF involves client activity as well, for instance if you use `f:ajax`. Of course a focus component is not shipped with standard jsf but with component libriaries like Primefaces ([see here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/focus.jsf))